# Collecting Performance metrics for kafka connect using hdfs sink connector

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, performance-testing, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are running kafka connect to get avro data from kafka topic and storing it a hdfs location using hdfs sink connector.
It basically stores 100 records (this is configuration through flush.size)to a single Avro record in hdfs location. I wanted to know how to calculate the performance metrics for it like no of records or messages written to hdfs location per second , bytes written per second, throughput , latency extra . We do not have kafka control center Configured also no jmx port enabled, through which it can be monitored like through jconsole.
Could this be calculated manually and how 
If any other tool exists which I can use like Jmeter , if yes then how
I want to calculate application specific metrics not on system level.

Comment: What do you have against enabling JMX?

Comment: The admin team have not configured and won't let us do as well

Comment: Well, the admin team should understand and accept that java applications need JMX exposed to collect performance metrics. AFAIK, there is nothing else you can do if you don't even have access to those machines yourself. And Jmeter is a load tester, not an monitoring tool , I believe. You could periodically run a consumer group offset script for the topic and plot that, but it'll only be number of messages, not size

Comment: Can we calculate manually through the number of no of records generated to hdfs location based on the timestamp and the with its size

Comment: Doing a MapReduce or whatever to count HDFS records would be slow, but you're welcome to do it

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong . I have three partitions directory created . I am going to check the latency that's no of bytes processed per second . Directly going to each partitions directly and doing Hadoop fs -ls -h  I would get size and timestamp  of each files , so copying it somewhere in notepad++ or excel , I will the total sizes it generated divide by the time duration that's starting timestamp and end time stamp . Will it be fine ?

Comment: I would rather do that in awk or python, but sure, you're welcome to do that by hand. My point is that just enabling JMX would probably be faster